# How to adapt a highstocks chart to a very narrow container?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

They want a 260px-wide highstocks chart! Understandably, this causes the range selector with its input controls to get written on top of itself. I see that I can disable the input controls but then I can't really see what range has been selected using the navigator.

Would I use an event to capture the range selected (in the rangeSelector or the navigator) and display it in a nearby control?

I'm using v1.3.9.  Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Using CSS style rule `overflow: scroll;` for your chart could help a little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can absolutely do that.

Highcharts provide events for these

you can find them

xAxis -> events -> afterSetExtremes/setExtremes

These 2 events will help you to capture the new limits when the range is changed. You can have your javascript code and work on it.

api ref : http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.events

you can find a worked out example along with some explanation in that link.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks.  I see that in the documentation jsfiddle that the report div is not filled when the page is first displayed, i.e., by the setting the rangeSelector.selected to 1 in the initialization. So if I disable the input boxes and set rangeSelector.selected like that and my user doesn't choose another range then he won't see the range that has been preselected.

Comment: yes i think i found how to do that. I'm accessing the xAxis[0].min/max on the chart load event.  Thanks.